# Why checkbox is not working using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 checkboxes in a view. When anyone of those is checked, I want to add `3` to the value of a javascript variable named `cost`. If anyone of the checkboxes is then unchecked, I want to subtract `3` from the value of `cost`.

Currently my code always subtracts `3` when a checkbox is checked or unchecked. How can I add `3` when a checkbox is checked?

HTML

```
<div class="panel-heading">Checkboxes</div>
<div id="chkbox" class="panel-body">
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsT)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsT, "T")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsS)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsS, "S")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsR)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsR, "R")
    </div>              
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var cost = @Session["Cost"];
$('#chkbox').change(function (chk) {
    debugger;               
    if ($(chk).prop("checked")){
        cost = cost + 3;
    } else {
        cost = cost- 3;
    }
    $("#product").val(cost);
    $("#spProduct").text(cost);
});
```

Comment: did you debug and see what is the value of  'chk'? i suspect $(chk).prop("checked") is not true alwys

Comment: What is `$(chk)`? that would return undefined and you will always execute the `if` block

Comment: I assume you want `if ($(this).is(':checked') {` - but you have not even indicated what the element with `id="chkbox"` is

Comment: @StephenMuecke, it is always executing else statement. `chk` gives me the selected checkbox.

Comment: @user9405863, Yes it is not always true. Why it is happening like this? Please suggest me.

Comment: @Raj, `chk` does not give the selected checkbox (its the event, not the element)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, then how to do this? Please guide me.

Comment: Read my previous comments

Comment: @StephenMuecke, that is always executing else statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168684/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-raj).

Comment: @Raj let me know if the problem not solved yet. i will help you

Comment: @user9405863, I followed Stephen answer and it solved it. Anyway, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element with `id="chkbox"` is a `<div>`, not a checkbox. When you use

```
$('#chkbox').change(function (chk) {
    if ($(chk).prop("checked")){
```

`chk` is the event, not an element (and an event does not have a `checked` property).

Give your checkboxes a class name and use that as a selector

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsT, new { @class = "mycheckbox" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsS, new { @class = "mycheckbox" })
....
```

and then the script becomes

```
$('.mycheckbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
```